# Slow-oxidative fibres vs fast-glycotic fibres

Tags: human-biology, physiology, muscles, mitochondria

Why do slow oxidative muscle fibres contain more mitochondria compared to fast-glycolytic muscle fibres?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the slow oxidative fibers compose mostly structural muscles (thing multifidus, longissimus, capitus muscles) which are "on" a lot of the time but don't retract quickly like fast glycolitic fibres. Because the SO muscles need to be active most of the day, they probably have higher energy requirements - whereas FG muscles can get by with less because you can store enough energy for occasional activation (you're not doing pushups all day). It's been a while, though.

Answer (score 4):

This is well-explained at the Wikipedia page on [skeletal striated muscle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_striated_muscle).

> There are two principal ways to categorize muscle fibers: the type of
>   myosin (fast or slow) present, and the degree of oxidative
>   phosphorylation that the fiber undergoes. Skeletal muscle can thus be
>   broken down into two broad categories: Type I and Type II. Type I
>   fibers appear red due to the presence of the oxygen binding protein
>   myoglobin. These fibers are suited for endurance and are slow to
>   fatigue because they use oxidative metabolism to generate ATP. Type II
>   fibers are white due to the absence of myoglobin and a reliance on
>   glycolytic enzymes. These fibers are efficient for short bursts of
>   speed and power and use both oxidative metabolism and anaerobic
>   metabolism depending on the particular sub-type. These fibers are
>   quicker to fatigue.

In the terms used in the article, the Type II fibers rely on anaerobic, glycolytic metabolism, whereas the Type I fibers use oxidative metabolism which, of course, requires mitochondria for the TCA cycle and oxidative phosphorylation.The Type I fibers also contain myoglobin which promotes rapid movement of O<sub>2</sub> through the cytosol to the mitochondrial ATP synthase.